# Change context root in grails 2

Tags: grails, contextroot, grails-2.0

I'm migrating an app from grails 1.3.6 to 2.0 and I need to change its context root. If I remember correctly, in 1.3.6 I installed the template plugin and changed:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>/newcontextroot</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I did the same in 2.0 with no success. Any hints ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can [configure](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/12/grails-goodness-change-context-path-of.html) the context in `Config.groovy`:

```
// grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
grails.app.context = '/newcontextroot'
```

or in `application.properties`:

```
app.context = /newcontextroot
```

Comment: Already tried that, but spring security core login keeps sending me to http://localhost/<i>appname</i>/login/auth?login_error=1, maybe it's a plugin problem

Comment: Is this when you've deployed a war, or just when you're using `run-app`? Or both?

Comment: Also, do you have any of [these properties](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/13%20URL%20Properties.html) in `Config.groovy` using a hard-coded context?

Comment: I've just tried with run-app and none of those properties exist in Config.groovy.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, there might be something else at work here? I've never had any problems using either of these ways to configure it...

Comment: Yup, maybe I should wait for 2.0.1 and try again.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I was trying to change the base URL that the application listens on and apparently grails.serverURL has no effect on how the application starts in tomcat. This property does.

Answer (score 2):

Start your grails application with this command

```
grails -Dapp.context=/ run-app
```

Answer (score 1):

In Grails version 3.3.9 I know changing:

**project/grails-app/conf/application.yml**

adding

```
server:
    contextPath: /yourcontextpath
    port: 9214
```

will do the trick.